# Node.js backend return response before all the API calls within the endpoints are made

Tags: node.js, api, express, promise

I have a GET endpoint, which basically makes some API calls to the Spoonacular API. Essentially, I make two API calls within the endpoint.

1. The first API call gets the list of recipe ID's for the specific ingredients
2. The second API calls gets the metadata for each of the recipe ID's.

After the first API call I store all the Id's in an array (recipeArray), and I want to make the second api call for each ID in my array (function recipeTest does this).

When I try to do this and then return my response to the front end, it always returns a response before completing all the API calls in the second step.

Here, is my code. The first API calls works just fine, but the second API call (recipeTest function), is where it messed up. Before that function finishes making all the API calls to the Spoonacular API, my endpoint returns an empty Array (res.send(toSend)). So, I was just wondering if there is any way around this?

Thank you so much in advance, I really appreciate it!

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    
    app.get('/api/search', async (req, res) => {
        console.log("endpoint working");

        let ingredientList = "apples,+eggs,+bacon"; // needs to be given from the front end
        let ingredientSearchUrl = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=${ingredientList}&number=1&ignorePantry=true&apiKey=${keys.spoonacularKey}`;

        try {
            const ingredientSearchResult = await axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: ingredientSearchUrl
            }); 
            var recipeArray = ingredientSearchResult.data.map(info => {
                return info.id;
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("error in finding recipe ID ", err);
        }

        let toSend = [];

        try {
            const check = await recipeTest(recipeArray, toSend);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("error in finding recipe information ", err);
        }
        
        res.send(toSend);
    });
}

const recipeTest = async (recipeArray, toSend) => {
    return Promise.all(
        _.forEach(recipeArray, async (recipeId) => {
            let recipeInfoUrl = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${recipeId}/information?includeNutrition=false&apiKey=${keys.spoonacularKey}`;
            let recipeInfo = {};
            const recipeData = await axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: recipeInfoUrl
            });
            // console.log("recipeInfo search working", recipeData.data);
            recipeInfo['id'] = recipeData.data.id;
            recipeInfo['title'] = recipeData.data.title;
            recipeInfo['time'] = recipeData.data.readyInMinutes;
            recipeInfo['recipeUrl'] = recipeData.data.sourceUrl;
            recipeInfo['imageUrl'] = recipeData.data.image;
            // console.log('recipe info dict', recipeInfo);
            toSend.push(recipeInfo);
            console.log('toSend inside', toSend);
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_.forEach` return collection itself and not all your async handlers.
Use `recipeArray.map` to get an array of async functions to let `Promise.all` do its work:

```
Promise.all(
        recipeArray.map(x => async (recipeId) => {
```